# Can Armadillo do eig_gen on Mat<float>?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, lapack, armadillo, blas

I am using Armadillo. I have these variables:

```
arma::Mat<float> m_matrix;
arma::cx_vec     m_eigenvalues;
arma::cx_mat     m_eigenvectors;
```

I want to do this:

```
void calculate_eigens ()
{
    arma :: eig_gen (m_eigenvalues, m_eigenvectors, m_matrix);
}
```

but the function prototype for `eig_gen` does not allow these parameter types, it wants the third argument to be a double-precision matrix.

Here are the gcc errors:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘eig_gen(arma::cx_vec&, arma::cx_mat&, arma::Mat&)’
>
> note: candidate: template typename arma::enable_if2<arma::is_supported_blas_type::value, arma::Col<std::complex > >::result arma::eig_gen(const arma::Base<typename T1::elem_type, T1>&)
>
> armadillo_bits/fn_eig_gen.hpp:25:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

This fixes it.

```
void calculate_eigens ()
{
    auto tmp = arma::conv_to<arma::Mat<double>>::from(m_matrix);

    arma :: eig_gen (m_eigenvalues, m_eigenvectors, tmp);
}
```

I don't want to do this conversion. I looked into Armadillo's source and it seems that `eig_gen` defers its main work to this function:

```
  template<typename eT>
  inline
  void
  geev(char* jobvl, char* jobvr, blas_int* N, eT* a, blas_int* lda, eT* wr, eT* wi, eT* vl, blas_int* ldvl, eT* vr, blas_int* ldvr, eT* work, blas_int* lwork, blas_int* info)
    {
    arma_type_check(( is_supported_blas_type<eT>::value == false ));

    if(is_float<eT>::value)
      {
      typedef float T;
      arma_fortran(arma_sgeev)(jobvl, jobvr, N, (T*)a, lda, (T*)wr, (T*)wi, (T*)vl, ldvl, (T*)vr, ldvr, (T*)work, lwork, info);
      }
    else
    if(is_double<eT>::value)
      {
      typedef double T;
      arma_fortran(arma_dgeev)(jobvl, jobvr, N, (T*)a, lda, (T*)wr, (T*)wi, (T*)vl, ldvl, (T*)vr, ldvr, (T*)work, lwork, info);
      }
    }
```

The `eT*a` parameter is passed in from `Mat<T>::get_ref` on `m_matrix`, so it seems to me like the library author intended for `eig_gen` to work happily on `Mat<float>` as well as `Mat<double>` but it doesn't work in practice.

How do I calculate the eigenvalues/eigenvectors on a `Mat<float>` without first converting to `Mat<double>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that all matrices and vectors have the same precision, not just the input matrix. The correct usage for single precision would be:

```
arma::fmat     X;
arma::cx_fvec  eigvals;
arma::cx_fmat  eigvecs;

// ... fill X with values ...

arma::eig_gen(eigvals, eigvecs, X);
```